# JMX Authentication files path in windows environment

Tags: java, windows, authentication, jmx

I am trying to add JMX auth in windows environment. I am referring : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

My usecase is that there are 100 odd desktop clients which we distribute via jar's. I want to package jmxaccess and jmxpassword file along with it. However my initial impression is (according to oracle doc) that i need to set up the password file in the JRE_HOME/lib/management directory. This will be very tedious to do for each user. Can someone please help me understand if we can provide custom paths in windows env. (similar to unix)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, the JRE_HOME.. path is the default. You can use a CMD option like

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/location/to/my/file
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/location/to/my/file -jar ...
```

> **com.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file:** Specifies location for password file. If
>   com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate is false, then this property
>   and the password and access files are ignored. Otherwise, the password
>   file must exist and be in the valid format. If the password file is
>   empty or nonexistent, then no access is allowed.
>
> **com.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file:** Specifies location for the access file. If
>   com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate is false, then this property
>   and the password and access files are ignored. Otherwise, the access
>   file must exist and be in the valid format. If the access file is
>   empty or nonexistent, then no access is allowed.
>   Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdevf